# JUNIT error on running myfeature.feature as cucumber JVM Test > potes.cucumberjvm.test.RunCucumberTest > Initialization Error

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

**Test Data :-**

1)Java  java version "1.8.0_121" Java(TM) SE Run-time Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

2)Eclipse   Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) Build id: 20161208-0600

3)OS    Microsoft Windows 10 Home - 64-Bit

**myFeature.feature**

```
Feature: This is my dummy feature file

Scenario: This is my first dummy scenario
Given This is my first dummy given step
When This is my second dummy given step
Then This is my third dummy given step
```

**steps.java**

```
package com.cucumber.mavenCucumberPrototype;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class steps
{
@Given("^This is my first dummy given step$")
public void This_is_my_first_dummy_given_step() throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println("Executed the first given step");
}
@When("^This is my second dummy given step$")
public void This_is_my_second_dummy_given_step() throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println("Executed the first when step");
}
@Then("^This is my third dummy given step$")
public void This_is_my_third_dummy_given_step() throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println("Executed the first then step");
}
}
```

**RunnerTest.java**

```
package com.cucumber.mavenCucumberPrototype;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:features"
            )

public class RunnerTest
{

}
```

**POM.XML**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenCucumberPrototype</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mavenCucumberPrototype</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**[Stack Trace :-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKUqF.jpg)**

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type cucumber.junit.Cucumber not present
at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:84)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.junit.Cucumber
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:349)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:10)
... 11 more
```

COmmand Line Output :-

```
C:\Users\Pragati Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype>mvn clean 
install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mavenCucumberPrototype 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ 
mavenCucumberPrototype ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Pragati 
Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ 
mavenCucumberPrototype ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Pragati 
Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ 
mavenCucumberPrototype ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
 [INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mavenCucumberPrototype ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Pragati 
   Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\src\test\resources
   [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
   mavenCucumberPrototype ---
  [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
  [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Pragati 
  Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\target\test-classes
  [INFO]
  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ 
  mavenCucumberPrototype ---
  [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Pragati 
  Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\target\surefire-reports

   -------------------------------------------------------
  T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.cucumber.mavenCucumberPrototype.RunnerTest
No features found at [classpath:features]

 0 Scenarios
 0 Steps
 0m0.000s
 Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.331 sec
 Results :
  Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
 [INFO]
 [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mavenCucumberPrototype 
  ---
 [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
 [INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Pragati 
 Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\target\mavenCucumberPrototype-
 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 [INFO]
 [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ 
 mavenCucumberPrototype ---
 [INFO] Installing C:\Users\Pragati 
 Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\target\mavenCucumberPrototype-
 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Pragati 
 Chaturvedi\.m2\repository\com\cucumber\mavenCucumberPrototype\0.0.1-
 SNAPSHOT\mavenCucumberPrototype-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 [INFO] Installing C:\Users\Pragati 
 Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\pom.xml to C:\Users\Pragati 
 Chaturvedi\.m2\repository\com\cucumber\mavenCucumberPrototype\0.0.1-
  SNAPSHOT\mavenCucumberPrototype-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 3.794 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-12T01:36:58-04:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/194M
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException`C:\Use
      rs\PragatiChaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\src\test\java\com\cu
      cumber\mavenCucumberPrototype>javac RunnerTest.java
        RunnerTest.java:5: error: package cucumber.api does not exist
        import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
                   ^
       RunnerTest.java:6: error: package cucumber.api.junit does not exist
     import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
                         ^
        RunnerTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        @CucumberOptions(
      ^
     symbol: class CucumberOptions
      RunnerTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
            ^
     symbol: class Cucumber
    4 errors 
 C:\Users\PragatiChaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype\src\test\java\com\ ucumber\mavenCucumberPrototype>javac steps.java
         steps.java:3: error: package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
                           ^
        steps.java:4: error: package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
                           ^
      steps.java:5: error: package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
                           ^
    steps.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    @Given("^This is my first dummy given step$")
    ^
    symbol:   class Given
     location: class steps
    steps.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    @When("^This is my second dummy given step$")
    ^
     symbol:   class When
    location: class steps
    steps.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    @Then("^This is my third dummy given step$")
    ^
    symbol:   class Then
    location: class steps
    6 errors

Comment: How did you run the test? If it was from your IDE, please try from command line to see if the error exists still

Comment: please dont use the comment section to these details. You can always edit your question. I believe you are not using 'maven clean verify' to run the test.

Comment: @djames: Thanks for your response. I have updated command line output in the question. However, I am getting error on running maven clean verify'  command as mention above

Comment: you should learn about maven. In this case run 'mvn clean verify' from C:\Users\Pragati Chaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype, or the folder in which your pom file resides.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with this in my POM.XML and it's works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberBasic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a maven project and *javac* is not the way to compile/build the project.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I would assume that you are not aware of maven. These are few tutorials on maven.

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-tutorial.html

Try running `mvn clean install` from C:\Users\PragatiChaturvedi\workspace\mavenCucumberPrototype and see if tests are getting executed.

Comment: No error on running mvn clean install command on executing from the directory where POM is located but I am getting the same error on running steps.java i.e. error: package cucumber.api does not exist

Comment: If running mvn install gives you no error this means that your tests are executed successfully and you should see the printlns in the console output.  javac on steps.java is not how you run the test case, but it is how you compile the classes.

Comment: If you found the answer to be useful use the checkbox to mark as accepted. That is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I can see from your maven output that tests are not getting executed. This is because you should specify your feature file in RunnerTest.java. It should be features = "classpath:myFeature.feature"

Comment: I have made this change but the issue is not resolved

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the output of mvn commandd after changing to what I suggested?